# Edit Master-Detail lookup field

Tags: lookup, master-detail

i created a master-detail relationship and definitely added a lookup value and saved the new record on the detail side.
 Now i wish to change the lookup field value to refer to some other value in the master. unable to do so - the edit record doesnt show the lookpu field as editable.

is this normal? any work around?
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is normal. To allow reparenting for Master-Detail, go into the field definition and tick the box Allow Reparenting.